# How would I print only the main function from a C source file?

Tags: linux, text-processing, terminal, c, source-code

For example, `cat foo.c` would print the whole file, `cat foo.c | grep main` will print the line where the main function is defined.

So how would I print the entire `main` function?

(I am on Ubuntu)

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @waltinator Why not?

Comment: I may just make a python script for this, If it works ill post it

Comment: Do you need to keep comments? And do you need to expand, ***or not*** expand macros?

Comment: Is the file formatted in a conventional way? If so then print from `main(` to a line containing just `}`, e.g. `sed -n '/main(/,/^}$/p' filename`.

Comment: You `grep` would also let you know where the substring `main` is used in any comment, string, variable name and function name. It will not only tell you where the `main` function occurs. Are you restricting yourself to current ANSI C or would you need to support functions with K&R C declarations too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends a lot on source and, control over source, desired result etc.

In it's simplest form:

```
sed -n '/^int main(/,/^}/p' file.c
```

That would print everything between lines starting with `int main(` until `}` inclusive.

---

If you need to *expand macros* you could use the c preprocessor `cpp` then run it trough `indent` and finally extract with `sed`. `indent` could in any case be OK to make sure the code is well formatted etc. Example:

- `cpp` expands macros. (Could be cumbersome on a big code base.)
- `indent` format the code for matching (indentation). The `-bls` options makes sure `int` and `main` is on same line.
- `sed` extract the `main` part.

```bsh
cpp file.c | 
indent --linux-style --standard-output -bls | 
sed -n '/^int main(/,/^}/p'
```

Or to mainly make sure indentation is OK:

```bsh
indent --linux-style --standard-output -bls file.c | 
sed -n '/^int main(/,/^}/p'
```

Optionally add `-fc1` to make comment blocks content not start in first column. (E.g. if a block comment has a line starting with `int main(`.)

---

Again; It all depends on how much control you have over the input, how much change you either want, do not want, need etc.

---

### Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define ANSWER(q, s) (q |= (s))
#define WHAT for

void foo(int a) {
    printf("%x\n", a | 2);
}

int

main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[])
{
    /* Some
     * comment
     * */
    int i, k = 40;
        ANSWER(k, 2);
    // Another comment
WHAT (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    foo(i);
}
    return 0;
}

/*

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}

*/
```

Result (using cpp, indent, sed):

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int i, k = 40;
    (k |= (2));

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        foo(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to find the line where `main` start, or any function for that matter, one option is also `ctags`, i.e:

```
$ ctags -x --c-kinds=f test.c | awk '$1 == "main"'
```

<sup>Have seen both `c-kinds` and `c-types` and both work, but `kinds` is the only one I have in manual. Perhaps something to do with `ctags` vs exuberant `ctags`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reformat the C source with `indent` and `cpp` (because you want to see it in its original, unmodified glory/hideousness), you could use perl's `Regexp::Common` module.  For example, using example.c from @ibuprofen's answer:

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common=balanced -0 -n -e \
    'm/(^\s*(?:int\s+)?\s*main\([^)]*\)\s*$RE{balanced}{-parens=>"{}"}\s*)/m
       and print $1' example.c
int

main(
    int argc,
    char *argv[])
{
    /* Some
     * comment
     * */
    int i, k = 40;
        ANSWER(k, 2);
    // Another comment
WHAT (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    foo(i);
}
    return 0;
}
```

This captures and prints the first regex pattern matching the definition of a `main` function, if it's present in the input.

The `m` at the *beginning* of the `m/.../m` operation is the perl regexp match operator. It's optional if you use the "standard" `/` delimiter, but required if you use a different delimiter (like `=` or `:` or one of the balanced delimiters like `{`..`}`). I like to use it even where it's not required.

The `m` at the *end* of the `m/.../m` is perl's multi-line string regex modifier, so that the regex can match across line boundaries.

The `\s*` at the end of the regex capture ensures that it captures any whitespace (including LF or CR+LF) at the end of the function's closing `}`.

or, same thing in a standalone script instead of a one-liner:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef $/; # enable slurp mode (read entire input at once)

use Regexp::Common qw(balanced);

while(<>) {
  m/(^\s*(?:int\s+)?\s*main\([^)]*\)\s*$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'{}'}\s*)/m
    and print $1;
};
```

This would also work pretty well instead of `sed` when combined with `indent` and `cpp`.  Which would also resolve the bug below (but there would be no real advantage over using sed, unless you also needed to use other `Regexp::Common` patterns like matching/extracting C comments, or other perl features):

BUGS: this will print the **first** `main` function found, whether it is commented out or not.